# mov instruction strange destination operand

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, cpu, bootloader

I am trying to understand the code for the Pintos bootloader and something struck me as strange in a certain line.

`addr32 movl %eax, init_ram_pages - LOADER_PHYS_BASE - 0x20000`

This line here is supposed to put the number of 4K pages in the variable init_ram_pages defined in a header file as:
`extern uint32_t init_ram_pages;`

What I do not understand is why are we subtracting from the `init_ram_pages` these values? What does it mean to have a subtraction operation in the destination operand of a `mov`?

**For further details:**  
The code which sets the size of the ram (in 4K pages) in %eax follows:
(if my understanding is correct)

```
    movb $0x88, %ah
    int $0x15
    addl $1024, %eax    # Total kB memory
    cmp $0x10000, %eax  # Cap at 64 MB
    jbe 1f
    mov $0x10000, %eax
1:  shrl $2, %eax       # (shift right by two = divide by 4)
                # now eax contains the number of 4K pages I guess?
```

The constant are defined as:

```
/* Kernel virtual address at which all physical memory is mapped.
   Must be aligned on a 4 MB boundary. */
#define LOADER_PHYS_BASE 0xc0000000     /* 3 GB. */
```

**Edit** 
The variable itself is defined in the same file as follows: (in the section of the file which follows the .code32)

```
#### Physical memory size in 4 kB pages.  This is exported to the rest
#### of the kernel.d
.globl init_ram_pages
init_ram_pages:
    .long 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtraction there is nothing special, it's just a simple assembly or link time operation. In the final binary, the result of the calculation will be present.

I assume this is the real-mode portion of the bootloader which is nevertheless assembled/linked using the protected mode memory map. The adjustment presumably translates between the protected mode address that the assembler generates the code for and the real mode addresses that the cpu will actually use when running this code.

Comment: Yes, this is in the real-mode portion of the bootloader; but it seems strange that I have to do the subtraction and translation manually between the protected and real-address mode considering that I set .code16

Comment: The assembler has no idea how you have set up the segment registers (both real and protected mode). So it can not translate between the two kinds of addresses.

Comment: (I've made an edit to the answer, kindly check it).

So if I get it correctly now, the variable was declared in the .32 section which gives it a protected mode 32-bit address then the subtraction was simply to point exactly to where it's residing while still running real-address mode?

Comment: One more thing, removing the defintion I posted in the edit from below the .code32 to below the .code16 doesn't change the behavior at all. Shouldn't this removal wreck havoc since now the variable is properely defined in the real-address mode area? or the linker will still locate it in protected mode addresses when it links to the rest of the kernel?

Comment: Just to expand on this answer, it looks like subtracting `LOADER_PHYS_BASE` converts the address of `init_ram_pages` from a kernel virtual address to a physical address. Subtracting `0x20000` converts the physical address to a DS relative offset, where the real mode DS value is `0x2000`.

Comment: .code16 just switches the code generation, doesn't affect anything else. There are no separate areas, in fact the 16 bit support is just a bolted-on hack in the gnu tools.